# Which solution is better for this predicate?

Tags: logic

We have this predicate:

> Prime(x) ≡ x>1 ∧(∀y)(Divide(y,x) → (y=1 ∨ y=x)).

Now I have to turn this into an English sentence. I've come up with three answers:

1) x is a prime number if x is greater than 1, and if for every given y that is divisible by x, then y is either 1 or x itself.

2) x is a prime number if x is greater than 1, and for every given y, if y is divisible by x, then y is either 1 or x itself.

3) x is a prime number if x is greater than 1, and if for every given y, if y is divisible by x, then y is either 1 or x itself.

Which one is correct and if none are correct, how should I write it?

Comment: You have "is divisible by" the wrong way around in all three proposals. It should be, "$y$ divides $x$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would render it as:

> A number is prime if and only if it is greater than $1$ and every number that divides it is either $1$ or the number itself.

But if you're in a classroom situation this might be *too English* to be accepted as a correct answer.

Your proposals are at a strange halfway point between English and formal logic (and they're really better answers to "how would you read this formula aloud?" than "how would you express this meaning in English?"), **but** this halfway point is apparently how authors of elementary logic textbooks often imagine English works, so it may work better for you to stick to that. You'll need to have a feel for the expectations in your particular class to make that choice.

If you choose to keep to the style you've started with, the variations between your proposal are minor grammar snags that don't have much *mathematical* significance. Once you have fixed the points Bram28 points out, these two variants would both be fine:

> 1. $x$ is a prime number if and only if $x$ is greater than $1$ *and* for every given $y$ that divides $x$, $y$ is either $1$ or $x$ itself.

Note that there is an if-then less than your own proposal. The relative clause "that divides $x$" itself expresses a conditional structure. The relative clause makes the sentence flow better as English, but it is a bit awkward to have the two formulas $x$ and $y$ separated only by a comma, which would be a reason to try to reword it.

> 2. $x$ is a prime number if and only if $x$ is greater than $1$ *and* for every given $y$, if $y$ divides $x$, then $y$ is either $1$ or $x$ itself.

In both of these variants the word "given" may be left out. It is not wrong, but it doesn't really say anything relevant either.

The extra "if" in your (3) is best avoided; it makes it sound like you're presenting two conditions that would *each* suffice for $x$ to be prime.

Answer (score 1):

As Henning points out in the comments, the $Divide(y,x)$ should be read as '$y$ divides $x$', so none of these are correct.

Also, you need an 'if and only if' instead of just an 'if', so in that respect all three are wrong as well.

Based on that, can you try again?